# addEventListener + setTimeout

Tags: javascript

It's the first time I encounter such an issue with the addEventListener() method.
When I try to use it with a setTimeout, the function is automatically called, even though the addEventListener has a "click" property.

`<button id="test">Test</button>`

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", setTimeout(myFunc, 2000));

function myFunc() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

Comment: because you call setTimeout and assign what it returns to the click handler. So since the timeout returns an id, you basically are doing  `...Listener("click", 133)`

Comment: the second argument to addEventListener needs to be a function, not, as you have, the result of calling a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be what you want.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(){setTimeout(myFunc, 2000)});

function myFunc() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` inside the function that you call.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4xpctfL/)

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", myFunc);

function myFunc() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Hello");
    }, 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the exact same code you have now but `curry` your function via `bind` vs. trying to invoke it while also trying to pass it as an argument.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", setTimeout.bind(null, myFunc, 2000));

function myFunc() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```