# setTimeout in event listener

Tags: javascript

I have some experience in html, css & javascript and I want to start make some projects... I want to make this [landing page](https://uicookies.com/demo/theme/landing/#section-faq) myself.

nav buttons onclick delay about .3 or .5 then scroll to the section
I tried using `setTimeout` in the event but It does not work.

Even I did not get any errors in the console.

I searched a lot about how to use `setTimeout()` in events but nothing worked.

Two codes that I tried:

```
function scrollToClick() {
    navbar.addEventListener('click', setTimeout(function (event) {
        const clicked = document.querySelector('#' + event.target.dataset.nav)
        clicked.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    }), 1000)
    
};
```

```
function scrollToClick() {
    setTimeout(function(){navbar.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        const clicked = document.querySelector('#' + event.target.dataset.nav)
        clicked.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"} );
    });}, 100)
    
};
```

*note: the code scroll no problem but it does not wait*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `setTimeout` inside the callback.

```js
function scrollToClick() {
    navbar.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        setTimeout( () => {
               const clicked = document.querySelector('#' + event.target.dataset.nav)
               clicked.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
         }, 1000)
    })
};
```

An example:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    setTimeout( () => {
          console.log("A clicked happend 1000ms ago")
     }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: That's how you should do it. See this simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706488/7910299. There is something wrong with your code somewhere else.

Comment: ok thanks, I will serach of another way to do that delay... if you know another way to delay please write it

Comment: I have another idea... what about make 2 js files, the first will do all my prev code and the second will use jQuery ```delay()``` function to do this? as it is in jquery more easier

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this delay method. Replace the inner lambda function with `console.log("clikced happend 1000ms ago")`. You will see that it correctly delays.

Comment: I added the example.